# Xcode Updating a table from another method

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a code_tab.m file which deals with the UI and code.m file which does the crunching of data and also updates a MutableArray. When the code.m updates the array I want to update the table in view linked to the connection_tab.m. I have a function in code_tab.m that has a:

```
[self.table tableupdate]
```

Which works as expected when called internally. When the same function is called from the code.m file (when the array has been updated) nothing happens even though I can see the same code is being accessed.

I have setup access by having this line in the code.h file:

```
    connection_tab* connectiontab_script;
```

and then calling it in code.m with

```
 connectiontab_script = [[connection_tab alloc] init];
[connectiontab_script tableupdate];
```

I've obviously missed something vital. Is there a way that one method can alter the visual display of another, in this case update the table already on screen?

Comment: You're creating another instance of your `connection_tab` and thus you're actually updating a table you can't see, not the one initially loaded. You need to pass through a reference to your initial `connection_tab` or look at using delegates.

Comment: Thats what I thought might be happening. How do you go about passing a reference to the initial connection_tab?

Comment: Can you show us how `connection_tab` communicates with your data class `code` please?

Comment: @GregularExpressions, Connection_tab communicates to an instance of code.m that is initiated in the AppDelegate. Connection_tab has the line `[appDelegate.connection_script initNetworkCommunication];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically **you should avoid having your data class make calls to methods in your view** as it will likely cause you headaches in future, [MVC](http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/a-quick-explanation-of-mvc/) is the recommended development practice.

However, you could achieve what you're trying to do by amending your `initNetworkCommunication` method in `code` to pass a reference to the active view through:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunicationForView:(UIViewController*)passedVC
```

Which you'd call from inside `connection_tab` like:

```
[appDelegate.connection_script initNetworkCommunicationForView:self];
```

Then in `code` you'd do (if statement avoids warnings):

```
if ([passedVC respondsToSelector:@selector(tableupdate)]) {
    [passedVC performSelector:@selector(tableupdate)];
}
```

Depending on the structure of your `code` class you may need to create a class-wide variable to store passedVC in if the `tableupdate` call isn't within `initNetworkCommunication`.

P.S You could also customize the method to be specific to your `connection_tab` class like:

```
- (void) initNetworkCommunicationForView:(connection_tab*)passedCT
```

Then you could ditch the selector stuff and go with:

```
[passedCT tableupdate];
```

But I went with UIViewController for compatibility reasons.